# li ul li is too long, line wraps but no indention

Tags: html, css

I've an unordered HTML list (`ul`). If the second word is too long the line wraps automatically but the overflowing text isn't indented.
Any ideas how to solve that?

[Here is the example](http://dr-raab.de/)

Then "Leistungen" and then click on KINDERZAHNHEILKUNDE. Now you see what I mean.

Probably it's because of the css, don't know about that.

Comment: The example url you have provided no longer has the issue... its worth using jsfiddle to demonstrate the issue instead of an actual website which might change

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Replace your indent with padding

```
padding-left: 2em;
text-indent: -2em;
```

Should do the trick

Comment: text-indent has done the trick. Thanks all for help, nickf this way is great, i'll use that the next time.
@sarfraz just changing the size is not what i want, the whole layout would be changed through floating.

Answer (score 13):

add this CSS:

```
ul {
    list-style-position: outside;
}
```

Example here: http://jsbin.com/emeda/

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisBeauchamp thanks, you're right. You can edit these yourself, you know. :)

Answer (score 2):

For my ordered list and the multi line indent I have followed below css

```
.surveyorderedlist{
        ol{
            list-style-position: outside;
        }
        li{
            margin-bottom:5px;
            margin-left:40px;
            padding-left:8px;
        }
    }
```

and then your html should be

```
<div class="surveyorderedlist">
            <span><b>Conditions imposed</b></span>
            <ol>
                <li>Names and addresses are accessed only by the Financial Service Provider on its own behalf, and solely for its own use;</li>
                <li>Names and addresses may only be accessed for a specified purpose;</li>
                <li>The fees charged for the provision of the names and addresses from the Motor Vehicle Register (MVR) are duly paid;</li>
                <li>Any instances of unauthorised access must immediately be notified to the Secretary for Transport and the Privacy Commissioner; </li>
            </ol>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

This is happening because the word **Prophylaxe in der Schwangerschaft** is too long to fit in that side bar. You need to increase the width of the sidebar containing your list.

The only other solution is to decrease the font size so that even words like above are shown as per width of the sidebar.

**EDIT** Please let me know if my answers is correct or not as i have some belief of that reason even though someone has -ve marked me; so please let me know if i am wrong by trying it out. thanks

Comment: I think the person probably voted you down because you insisted that rdesign needed to change what he wanted his site to look like, when there was infact a way for him to achieve the effect he desired. Voting down is not necessarily a punishment to you, rather a way of warning potential viewers that the answer supplied is incorrect.