# jquery iterate ul within li

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm using the  following code to iterate the HTML element given below

```
<ul id="sortable">
<li>
<p> item 1</p>
<ul id="nested-sortable">
  <li>
     Sub item 1 
  </li>
  <li>
     Sub item 2
  </li>
  <li>
     Sub item 3 
  </li>
</ul>
</li>
<li>
<p> item 2</p>
</li>
</ul>
```

Javascript

```
var jsonSeqObj = {};
alert('hi');
$('ul#sortable li').each(function(index,pele) {
   alert($(pele).attr('id'));
   $(pele).children('ul#nested-sortable li').each(function(idx, chele) {
   alert(chele.attr('id'));
   jsonSeqObj.push({REF_ID:$(chele).attr('id') , NEW_SEQ_NO:idx });
});  
jsonSeqObj.push({REF_ID:$(pele).attr('id') , NEW_SEQ_NO:index });
});
```

[li ul li is too long, line wraps but no indention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867358/li-ul-li-is-too-long-line-wraps-but-no-indention)

```
alert(jsonSeqObj);
return jsonSeqObj;
```

but the children thing is not working

ERROR : Object doesnt support this property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your markup same as in the example? Or you have more than one nested-sortable ul-s? Maybe problem that you have duplicated IDs on the page (Id should be unique).

Comment: oryol  i have more nested sortable ul

Comment: In such case you shouldn't assign same ID for many items. Use class, for example.

Comment: Could you please post (maybe edit your initial question) real current markup and JS code?

Answer (score 0):

`alert(chele.attr('id'));`
But chele here is DOM object (not jQuery), so it doesn't have attr method. That's why you are getting 'object doesn't support this prperty...'