# Restore CSS of unordered list after being reset to zero

Tags: html, css

My default CSS resets a bunch of values to zero, most applicable to this question, it does `ol, ul, li {margin: 0;padding: 0;}`

I now have a need for a typical unordered list with bullets and text that wraps and keeps the same indention on the wrapped text.  I found a bunch of posts related to the subject ([How to keep indent for second line in ordered lists via CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10428720/how-to-keep-indent-for-second-line-in-ordered-lists-via-css), [li ul li is too long, line wraps but no indention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867358/li-ul-li-is-too-long-line-wraps-but-no-indention)), but later found that the cause of my issues was resetting the padding and margins to zero!

How do I restore the CSS of an unordered list after it was reset to zero so that the text after each bullet lines up in a column?  Below is my attempt, but it only works with FireFox.

http://jsfiddle.net/48By2/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Testing</title>  
        <style type="text/css">
            ol, ul, li {margin: 0;padding: 0;} /* Default reset */

            ul {
                width:300px;
                margin: 1em 0;
                -moz-padding-start: 40px;
            }
        </style> 
    </head>

    <body>
        <ul>
            <li>
                omnis ab quasi voluptatem voluptatem consequuntur sed fugit beatae veritatis sed quae dolores iste quasi ipsam ipsam, perspiciatis sed inventore eaque totam inventore sed ut sit dolores perspiciatis inventore ipsa totam ipsam ipsam, 
            </li>
            <li>
                et consequuntur error totam quia ipsa odit aspernatur accusantium vitae ipsam ipsam, enim voluptatem eaque ratione vitae ipsam qui odit ratione enim ipsa ipsa natus quae laudantium quae rem 
            </li>
            <li>
                nemo ab ratione sunt sit rem magni sit fugit unde unde, inventore magni magni ab qui eos ab natus sunt nemo ab fugit
            </li>
            <li>
                omnis error rem enim ipsam ipsam, perspiciatis qui eos inventore laudantium vitae quasi voluptas eaque aut error vitae voluptatem consequuntur aspernatur consequuntur inventore fugit qui ipsa ipsa, quia 
            </li>
            <li>
                ipsa ipsam ipsam illo explicabo sit vitae vitae, qui doloremque quae aspernatur aperiam beatae ratione ut aperiam sed dicta qui ipsam ipsa voluptatem voluptatem, error ratione aut rem ipsa 
            </li>
            <li>
                omnis ab quasi voluptatem voluptatem consequuntur sed fugit beatae veritatis sed quae dolores iste quasi ipsam ipsam, perspiciatis sed inventore eaque totam inventore sed ut sit dolores perspiciatis inventore ipsa totam ipsam ipsam, 
            </li>
            <li>
                et consequuntur error totam quia ipsa odit aspernatur accusantium vitae ipsam ipsam, enim voluptatem eaque ratione vitae ipsam qui odit ratione enim ipsa ipsa natus quae laudantium quae rem 
            </li>
            <li>
                omnis ab quasi voluptatem voluptatem consequuntur sed fugit beatae veritatis sed quae dolores iste quasi ipsam ipsam, perspiciatis sed inventore eaque totam inventore sed ut sit dolores perspiciatis inventore ipsa totam ipsam ipsam, 
            </li>
            <li>
                et consequuntur error totam quia ipsa odit aspernatur accusantium vitae ipsam ipsam, enim voluptatem eaque ratione vitae ipsam qui odit ratione enim ipsa ipsa natus quae laudantium quae rem 
            </li>
            <li>
                omnis ab quasi voluptatem voluptatem consequuntur sed fugit beatae veritatis sed quae dolores iste quasi ipsam ipsam, perspiciatis sed inventore eaque totam inventore sed ut sit dolores perspiciatis inventore ipsa totam ipsam ipsam, 
            </li>
            <li>
                et consequuntur error totam quia ipsa odit aspernatur accusantium vitae ipsam ipsam, enim voluptatem eaque ratione vitae ipsam qui odit ratione enim ipsa ipsa natus quae laudantium quae rem 
            </li>
            <li>
                omnis ab quasi voluptatem voluptatem consequuntur sed fugit beatae veritatis sed quae dolores iste quasi ipsam ipsam, perspiciatis sed inventore eaque totam inventore sed ut sit dolores perspiciatis inventore ipsa totam ipsam ipsam, 
            </li>
            <li>
                et consequuntur error totam quia ipsa odit aspernatur accusantium vitae ipsam ipsam, enim voluptatem eaque ratione vitae ipsam qui odit ratione enim ipsa ipsa natus quae laudantium quae rem 
            </li>
            <li>
                omnis ab quasi voluptatem voluptatem consequuntur sed fugit beatae veritatis sed quae dolores iste quasi ipsam ipsam, perspiciatis sed inventore eaque totam inventore sed ut sit dolores perspiciatis inventore ipsa totam ipsam ipsam, 
            </li>
            <li>
                et consequuntur error totam quia ipsa odit aspernatur accusantium vitae ipsam ipsam, enim voluptatem eaque ratione vitae ipsam qui odit ratione enim ipsa ipsa natus quae laudantium quae rem 
            </li>
        </ul>
    </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Just in case it is that: `-moz-padding-start` will only work in firefox as `-moz-` is the prefix for mozilla. You have to use the other prefixes too for the other browsers, such as `-webkit-, -ms-, etc..` and the non-prefix one off course.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl  Yes, I just learned about `-moz-`  Too many choices!  I think I like the non-prefix ones best.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code works only in firefox as you only use the `-moz-` prefix for `padding-start`.

Adding the `-webkit-` prefix `-webkit-padding-start: 40px;` for example makes you fiddle work fine in Chrome too.

Adding the following will cover a few more:

```
ul {
    width:300px;
    margin: 1em 0;
    -moz-padding-start: 40px;
    -webkit-padding-start: 40px;
    -ms-padding-start: 40px; /* IE does not supported it so -ms- prefix is redundant */
    padding-start: 40px;
}
```

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/6sxdL/) - adding other browser's prefixes

---

You can off course also use `padding-left: 40px` if you feel more comfortable using already standardised CSS.

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/pr8xL/) - Using already standardised CSS: `padding-left: 40px`

---

`padding-start` is part of the mozilla extensions, hence the `-moz-` prefix.
According to [**their documentation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-moz-padding-start) `padding-start` is only supported in Firefox and webkit based browsers, such as Safari and Chrome.

Definitely does not look like a cross-browser standard.

Comment: Thanks Francois.  Just learned about all these browser specific prefixes.  Looking at http://www.iecss.com/, they do not use padding-start, but use `padding: 0 0 0 30pt;`.  I am a little confused.  Is `padding-start` even valid CSS?

Comment: I would not use this, padding-start has limited support. I'm not voting down because you are very right about why it wasn't working cross-browser, but using the padding-start property for something that you can use padding or margin for is ill-advised.

Comment: @Ian: I totally agree in that I would recommend the use of non prefixed padding/margin if those will do the job. I also added extra info in regards `padding-start` being a mozilla extension only support in mozilla and webkit based browsers.

Answer (score 3):

Use a class name, this is basic CSS. Unless there is a reason why you can't, your question is a little confusing.

```
ul.normalList li {
    width:300px;
    margin: 1em;
    list-style-type: disc;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/iancwoodward/48By2/5/

Answer (score 2):

try

`padding: 0 40px;`

that seemed to work on your fiddle, heres the update

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rudigerkidd/48By2/4/)

Comment: Thanks.  I've been messing around with this for over an hour, and I just stumbled on using `padding: 0 0 0 30pt;`

Comment: @user1032531 no worries

Comment: This will work but it will nullify your reset (in other words your reset is pointless if you use padding because it's just replacing the margin). You should add a class as I recommended for the uls you want to have padding.